# Getting Error with Date Format in To_Char

Tags: oracle, date, to-char, sysdate, sysdatetime

I am getting error in the second script. Please explain why i am getting error in the second script.

> > select count(*) from LCL_SHR_IncidentIntegrationInt where 
> >     externalsystem = 'IPSOFT' 
> >     and (to_char(sysdate,'**YYYYMMDDHH24MISS**')-to_char(fn_adjusted_date(CREATE_DATE),'**YYYYMMDDHH24MISS**')) > 180;
> >
> > **O/P : 122797**
> >
> > select count(*) from LCL_SHR_IncidentIntegrationInt where 
> >     externalsystem = 'IPSOFT' 
> >     and (to_char(sysdate,'**DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS**')-to_char(fn_adjusted_date(CREATE_DATE),'**DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS**')) > 180;
> >
> > **O/P :** ORA-01722: invalid number
> >     01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> >     *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> >     *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: You convert two dates to character strings and then try to subtract one of those character strings from the other.

Comment: What do you expect the mathematical expression of "27-10-2015 11:07:46" minus  "27-10-2015 10:07:46" to result in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query works because Oracle is able to implicitly cast the characters as number and compare with 180. The other one doesn't because the : and - cannot be implicitly cast to number.
You should use date and time functions for such cases like `timestampdiff` or `datediff`. More functions here - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers

Comment: Can you please vote as correct answer if that solved your problem? Thanks.